# powerline shows only solid green bar on emacs + OSX Terminal

Tags: emacs, powerline

I'm a Vim user getting up to speed on Emacs. One of my favorite plugins for Vim is [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline), and I'm looking for the same functionality. The default Emacs bar is pretty fugly ...

So, I've installed bits and pieces in my ~/.emacs.el, and I *do* see a new bar at the bottom, but it's just a solid green line -- no useful infos.

One wrinkle, I am running this from the OSX Terminal. Emacs 26.2, OSX 10.13.6 .

I did find [this post](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/master/troubleshooting.html#in-tmux-there-is-a-green-bar-in-place-of-powerline) which seems to be exactly the problem. I cloned the powerline repo and pointed `$POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND` to the config script as suggested in those docs ... nothin.

Here's how it looks currently:

[image: green-bar]

My config from `~/.emacs.el`:

```
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/emacs-powerline")
(require 'powerline)
```

Any suggestions welcome ... Many thanks !!

Comment: You _probably_ need a TrueColor capable terminal app (ITerm2 or kitty). You _definately_ need a patched font.

Comment: many thanks @nega, I'll give that a shot.